# When importing from a python module is it a class that gets imported or a function?

Tags: python, python-import, python-datetime

In Code Academy's python training there's a lesson about importing datetime. The syntax is:

from *datetime* import *datetime*

After importation I'm able to write **now = datetime.now()** and evaluate **now.hour**, **now.minute** and **now.second**. I see in the datetime module that .now (), .hour, .minute and .second are defined in the datetime class. Which leads me to interpret the import statement as saying:

from *datetime module* import *datetime class*

And so it seems that access to the datetime class is what gave me access to the .now(), .hour, .minute and .second definitions.

But later I discovered that I'm also able to evaluate **now.month**, **now.day** and **now.year**. Even though .month .day and .year are **not** in the datetime class. Rather they're in a different class called **date**.

How could I access definitions from the date class when it seems I only imported the datetime class?

Comment: Your question title is quite different than what you're actually asking in the question body. To answer the title: It depends! You can import classes and functions, but you can also import other things too. If you use `import some_module`, you'll get a module object (which probably contains other things). If you use `from some_module import some_name`, you'll get whatever object `some_name` references in `some_module` (it could be a class or a function, but could also be any other kind of object). There's no way to know (without reading the module documentation) what type of object you'll get.

Comment: The title reflects my initial misunderstanding about classes vs functions. I just started learning programming this weekend. As I was typing the body I managed to flesh out my actual question but forgot to change the title. Either way, I'm glad you answered the title specifically because I just learned something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look through the source of `datetime.py`, you'll notice this line (line 1290 in 3.4.2):

```
class datetime(date):
```

This is the class definition for the `datetime` class, which is inheriting from the previously-defined `date` class. Therefore, a datetime object (an instantiation of the `datetime` class) can access properties and methods defined in the `date` class, as long as they were not overridden by `datetime`.

You can read more about classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), and about inheritance in particular [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Comment: Ahhh! That explains it very well. Gracias.